# Getting all paths in tree traversal in c#

Tags: c#, list, queue, tree-traversal

Having a function like below to return all paths from a Node object.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Paths(Node root)
{
    var queue = new Queue<Tuple<string, Node>>();
    queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<string, Node>(root.Account.ToString(), root));

    while (queue.Any())
    {
        var node = queue.Dequeue();
        if (node.Item2.Children.Any())
        {
            foreach (var child in node.Item2.Children)
            {
                queue.Enqueue(new Tuple<string, Node>(node.Item1 + "-" + child.Account, child));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            yield return node.Item1;
        }
    }
}
```

The Node object is defined as follows..(Its a Ledger account with a variable number of sum accounts as children)

```
public class Node
{
  public string Account { get; set; }
  public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
  public Node(string account)
  {
    Account = account;
    Children = new List<Node>();
  }
}
```

For testing below object is used

```
var root = new Node("1")
{
    Children = new List<Node>
    {
        new Node("2") { Children = new List<Node> {new Node("5"), new Node("6"), new Node("7") } },
        new Node("3"),
        new Node("4"){ Children = new List<Node> {new Node("7") } }
    }
};
```

and called like this

```
var allPaths = Paths(root);
```

The output is is correct but a text representation of all the paths

```
[0] "1-3"
[1] "1-2-5"
[2] "1-2-7"
[3] "1-2-"
[4] "1-4-7"
```

But instead of an string representation of the path i need a list with a list of node object `List<List<Node>>`

ex.

```
[0]
    [0] 1
    [1] 3
[1]
    [0] 1
    [1] 2
    [2] 5
[2]
    [0] 1
    [1] 2
    [2] 6
[3]
    [0] 1
    [1] 2
    [2] 7
[4]
    [0] 1
    [1] 4
    [2] 7
```

So what changes to the Paths function do i need in order to get the desired output..

Any help i more than welcome.

Comment: So instead of starting with and adding to a string, you want to start with some kind of list and add to that?  See where the code is creating and adding to this string, and replace it with correspond operations using a list.

Comment: Yes the idea was to have a List with all the different paths as List<node> objects. Im trying to make some changes to existing code due to new output demands. Im not a seasoned/experienced developer so im not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: See where the current code is creating and adding to this string, and replace it with corresponding operations using a list.